# Добавить класс одному div и убрать у другого

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть 2 блока Зеленый и Желтый, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на зеленый, выдавался зеленый блок, а при нажатии желтого - желтый, а так же чтобы проверка.
Я пытался сделать через classList.add\remove, но должного результата не получил, в чем может быть ошибка?

```js
var green = document.getElementsByClassName('green');
var yellow = document.getElementsByClassName('yellow');
var greenCoint = document.getElementById('greenCoint');
var yellowCoint = document.getElementById('yellowCoint');

green[0].onclick = function() {
  yellowCoint[0].classList.add("hidden");
  greenCoint[0].classList.remove("hidden");
}
yellow[0].onclick = function() {
  greenCoint[0].classList.add("hidden");
 yellowCoint[0].classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.green {
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="green btn">
  <p>green button</p>
</div>
<div class="yellow btn">
  <p>yellow button</p>
</div>

<div class="coint green" id="greenCoint">
  <p>50</p>
</div>
<div class="coint yellow hidden" id="yellowCoint">
  <p>100</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `ID` уникален, не может на странице  быть двух одинаковых  `ID` и это значит, что `index` не нужен.

Не

```
 greenCoint[0].classList.add("hidden");
 yellowCoint[0].classList.remove("hidden");
```

А

```
 greenCoint.classList.add("hidden");
 yellowCoint.classList.remove("hidden");
```

```js
var green = document.getElementsByClassName('green');
var yellow = document.getElementsByClassName('yellow');
var greenCoint = document.getElementById('greenCoint');
var yellowCoint = document.getElementById('yellowCoint');

green[0].onclick = function() {
  yellowCoint.classList.add("hidden");
  greenCoint.classList.remove("hidden");
}
yellow[0].onclick = function() {
  greenCoint.classList.add("hidden");
  yellowCoint.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.green {
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="green btn">
  <p>green button</p>
</div>
<div class="yellow btn">
  <p>yellow button</p>
</div>

<div class="coint green" id="greenCoint">
  <p>50</p>
</div>
<div class="coint yellow hidden" id="yellowCoint">
  <p>100</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С id задолбаетесь редактировать код, как только кнопок станет чуть больше двух. В таких случаях легче один раз записать для классов и забыть.

Изначально все блоки невидимые, а класс show добавляет им видимость:

```js
let btn  = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

btn.forEach(function(e, index){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    bubu.forEach( function(el){ el.classList.remove('show') } );
    //Сперва убрали класс видимости со всех блоков без разбора
    
    bubu[index].classList.add('show');
    //Потом добавили его на текущий.
    // index - номер кликнутой кнопки совпадает с номером блока, который надо показать
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
  user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.btn:hover { box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #555; transform: translateY(-1px); }
.btn:active { box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #555; transform: translateY(0); }

.bubu { display: none; padding: 5px; margin: 15px 0; }
.bubu.show { display: block; }

.yellow { background-color: #ed0; }
.green { background-color: green; color: white; }
.orange { background-color: #f36700; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="btn green">Green button</div>
<div class="btn yellow">Yellow button</div>
<div class="btn orange">Orange button</div>

<div class="bubu green show">50</div>
<div class="bubu yellow">100</div>
<div class="bubu orange">150</div>
```

[Подробнее про forEach...](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration)

Если с этим кодом ничего не понятно, можете посмотреть первый пример тут → [JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css/982073#982073)